# LINQ to Entities: Workaround needed for query on primary key

Tags: linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services

While using LINQ to Entities in a Silverlight app, when a query is generated on the primary key of a table:

```
var query = (from b in PHOTOS
where b.RECORDID == selectedRecordId
select b);
```

it looks like this `http://localhost/DataService.svc/PHOTOS('123456')`.  This is OK until one needs to use the same code with an old DB that (astonishingly) did not enforce the PK constraint.  The result is one record returned followed by an error:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>A single resource was expected for the result, but multiple resources were found.</message>
    <type>System.InvalidOperationException</type>
    <stacktrace>   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.Serializer.WriteRequest(IEnumerator queryResults, Boolean hasMoved)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.ResponseBodyWriter.Write(Stream stream)</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
```

This problem goes away if I rewrite the query by hand like this: `http://localhost/DataService.svc/PHOTOS()?$filter=RECORDID eq '123456'`.  How can I write the LINQ code so that it forces it to use the $filter instead of the PK in parentheses?  All of the results from this table are needed, so just grabbing the first one won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var query = (from b in PHOTOS
             where b.RECORDID == selectedRecordId
             select b).FirstOrDefault;
```

This will force a single result (or the object's default, typically Nothing, if there isn't a record with that ID).

**Edit:**

Second attempt at a solution based on the comment below, which I can't verify at the moment without an IDE in front of me:

```
var query = (from b in PHOTOS
             select b).Where(p => p.RECORDID == selectedRecordId);
```

My reasoning is that moving the `where` clause outside the initial query may force it to be a filter.

Should this not work, my only other thought is to look at modifying the EF schema to override PHOTOS to force it to not have a primary key.

Comment: Upvote for an valid workaround, but I left out 2 important details in my question; edited above.  Specifically, this doesn't work with an async Silverlight call.

Comment: Edited with a couple other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas.  Appending the Where() does not fix the problem, which doesn't surprise me because I remember learning that the 2 forms were functionally identical.  Clearly, modifying the schema would fix the problem, too, but that's not an option.